# The request was aborted: The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, garbage-collection, httpwebrequest

> **Just wanted to add that after adding code given in this question , I did not find this error happening again. I think Garbage Collection did the trick.**

I am struggling to deal with the above error. I have two asp.net web applications. One of them is treated as Server and other as Client. I am using Hessian Encoding method to handle web requests and responses.

Initially , my client and server responds to each other 100% correctly .but after sometime my client stops contact my server , and I received this error:

> The request was aborted: The operation has timed out

I have tried so many things which I found on internet to resolve my problem. first thing I did was the closing of request and response streams.

Then I added following properties:

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.Proxy = null;

request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;
```

after that I added ReadWriteTime out and GC.Collect().

but all my efforts ended in no result.

This problem only occurs on of the GoDaddy server , my project is working aboslutely fine on my local server and of my another physical server. I also not get this error when running the projects from my localhost.

It occured only when I deploy to my GoDaddy server or I connect my local client to my GoDaddy Server.

From log I can see that request stops reaching to the server end.

here is my final code:

```
// Send Request to Edge Server. Will receive a response as an Encoded stream
        String infoMessage = "userId Is: " + request.Info.UserId.AsString() + " Session Id is: " + request.Info.SessionId.AsString();
        String logMessage = "inside Invoke: " + infoMessage;
        Stream requestStream = null;
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;
        Stream responseStream = null;
         HttpWebRequest webRequest=null;
        try
        {
            // Construct web request
            logMessage = "Creating webrequest to: " + url + " " + infoMessage;
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.ContentType = encoderType.Trim().ToLower();
            webRequest.Method = REQUEST_METHOD;
            webRequest.Timeout = 120000;
            webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 120000;
            webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            webRequest.Proxy = null;
            webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
            webRequest.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;
            logMessage = logMessage + "Timeout is 5000 Keep Alive False";


            logMessage = "timout is: " + webRequest.Timeout.ToString() + logMessage;
            // Encode Request object as Stream
            requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            EncoderFactory.GetInstance(this.encoderType).Encode(requestStream, request);
            logMessage = "going to getresponse" + logMessage;
            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            logMessage = "Response returend" + logMessage;
            // Recieve web response
            String contentType = webResponse.ContentType;
            logMessage = "going to get response stream" + logMessage;
            responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

            // If response Content Type is 'text/html' then assume it's an error message
            if (contentType.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith("text/html"))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
                String errorMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                return new ErrorResponse(-1000, logMessage + " " + errorMessage);
            }
            else if (contentType.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith(EncoderFactory.ENCODER_TYPE_HESSIAN))
            {
                // Decode Response object from Stream
                return (Response)EncoderFactory.GetInstance(this.encoderType).Decode(responseStream);
            }
            else
            {
                return new ErrorResponse(-1001, "Invalid response - ContentType='" + contentType + "'");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return new ErrorResponse(-1002, "Exception is -1002 and Message is = " + ex.Message + " " + logMessage + ".");
        }
        finally
        {

            // Close request stream
            if (requestStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    requestStream.Flush();
                    requestStream.Close();
                }
                catch { }
            }

            // Close web response
            if (webResponse != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    webResponse.Close();
                }
                catch { }
            }

            // Close response stream
            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    responseStream.Flush();
                    responseStream.Close();
                }
                catch { }
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```